# Error Msg 213: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a table with a stored procedure and I'm trying to insert data into it, but I'm getting this error

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 49
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@EmployeeID")

Please help!

```
Create Table Humanresource.Employee
(
    EmployeeID char(3) constraint pkemployeeid primary key,
    FirstName varchar(20) not null,
    LastName varchar(20) not null,
    Emp_Address varchar(30) not null,
    Title char(30) constraint ckTitle check(Title in ('Executive','Senior Executive','Management Trainee','Event Manager','Senior Event Manager')),
    Phone varchar(20) check(Phone like '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]')
)
```

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure Auto_EmpID
    @FirstName varchar(20),
    @LastName varchar(20),
    @Address varchar(30),
    @Title varchar(30),
    @Phone varchar(20)
AS
   Declare @EmployeeID char(3)

   if exists (select EmployeeID From HumanResource.Employee Where EmployeeID = 'E101')
   BEGIN
      Select 
         @EmployeeID = Max(right(EmployeeID, 2))
      from HumanResource.Employee

      Select 
         @EmployeeID = CASE
                         When @EmployeeID >= 0 AND @Employeeid < 9 
                           Then 'E0' + convert(char(3), @EmployeeID + 1)
                         When @EmployeeID >= 9 AND @EmployeeID < 99  
                           Then 'E' + convert(char(3), @EmployeeID + 1)
                       END
    END
    Else
       set @Employeeid = 'E101'


    insert into HumanResource.Employee
    Values(@EmployeeID, @FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @Title, @Phone)

    Return 

    Exec Auto_EmpID 'Bamidele','Ajose','Lagos','11-1111-111-111'
    exec Auto_Empid 'Kunle','Awele','Ikeja','22-3332-655-897'
    exec auto_empid 'John','George','Benin','33-5555-7654-443'

    select * from humanresource.employee

    insert into humanresource.employee(@EmployeeID, @FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @Title, @Phone)
    values(@EmployeeID = 'e101', 'Baley', 'Carles', 'Los Angeles', '23-3445-434-344')
```

Answer (score 2):

These 2 lines have a lot of problems:

```
insert into humanresource.employee(@EmployeeID,@FirstName,@LastName,@Address,@Title,@Phone)
values(@EmployeeID='e101','Baley','Carles','Los Angeles','23-3445-434-344')
```

1. You don't need to prefix the @ symbol to column names. That should only be used with variables.
2. The column list contains 6 columns, but you are only supplying 5 values in the `values` clause. Please add the 6th value or remove the column where you don't want to insert.
3. If you want to use the value 'e101', you can directly insert that. If you want to use the variable `@employeeID`, just pass that. The assignment `@employeeID = 'e101'` is wrong inside the `values` clause. You could just do `set @employeeID = 'e101` to assign the value before the `insert` statement.
4. `@employeeID` is declared as `char(3)`, so even if you wanted to assign the value 'e101' to it before the `insert statement`, the value would get truncated to 'e10'. So, you must declare it as `char(4)` at least.

Another thing is that your stored procedure takes 5 input parameters, but you pass only 4 when calling it. If you want to pass only some parameters instead of all, you need to specify default values for each parameter while creating the procedure, something like this:

```
create procedure Auto_EmpID
@FirstName varchar(20) = 'somefirstname',
@LastName varchar(20) = 'somelastname',
@Address varchar(30) = 'somecity',
@Title varchar(30) = 'sometitle',
@Phone varchar(20) = '111-111-111'
```